# c++11: what is its gc interface, and how to implement?

Tags: c++11, garbage-collection

I was watching Bjarne Stroustrup's talk "[The Essence of C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86xWVb4XIyE)".

In 44:26 he mentioned "C++11 specifies a GC Interface".

May I ask what is the interface, and how to implement it?
Any more detailed good introduction online, or some sample codes to demonstrate it pls?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stroustrup extends this discussion in his [C++ FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#gc-abi), the thing is that GC usage is optional, library vendors are free to implement one or not :

> Garbage collection (automatic recycling of unreferenced regions of
>   memory) is **optional** in C++; that is, a garbage collector is not a
>   compulsory part of an implementation. However, **C++11 provides a
>   definition of what a GC can do if one is used** and an ABI (Application
>   Binary Interface) to help control its actions.
>
> The rules for pointers and lifetimes are expressed in terms of "safely
>   derived pointer" (3.7.4.3); roughly: "pointer to something allocated
>   by new or to a sub-object thereof." 
>   to ordinary mortals: [...]

The functions in the C++ standard supporting this (the "interface" to which Stroustrup is referring to)  are :

- [`std::declare_reachable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/declare_reachable)
- [`std::undeclare_reachable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/undeclare_reachable)
- [`std::declare_no_pointers`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/declare_no_pointers)
- [`std::undeclare_no_pointers`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/undeclare_no_pointers)

These functions are presented in [the N2670 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2670.htm) :

> Its purpose is to support both garbage collected implementations and
>   reachability-based leak detectors. This is done by giving undefined
>   behavior to programs that "hide a pointer" by, for example, xor-ing it
>   with another value, and then later turn it back into an ordinary
>   pointer and dereference it. Such programs may currently produce
>   incorrect results with conservative garbage collectors, since an
>   object referenced only by such a "hidden pointer" may be prematurely
>   collected. For the same reason, reachability-based leak detectors may
>   erroneously report that such programs leak memory.

Either your implementation supports "strict pointer safety" in which case implementing a GC is possible, or it has a "relaxed pointer safety" (by default), in which case it is not. You can determine that by looking at the result of [`std::get_pointer_safety()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/get_pointer_safety), if available.

I don't know of any actual standard C++ GC implementation, but at least **the standard is preparing the ground for it to happen**.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the good answer by [quantdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510483/quantdev), which I've upvoted, I wanted to provide a little more information here (which would not fit in a comment).

Here is a C++11 conforming program which demonstrates whether or not an implementation supports the GC interface:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int
main()
{
#ifdef __STDCPP_STRICT_POINTER_SAFETY__
    std::cout << __STDCPP_STRICT_POINTER_SAFETY__ << '\n';
#endif
    switch (std::get_pointer_safety())
    {
    case std::pointer_safety::relaxed:
        std::cout << "relaxed\n";
        break;
    case std::pointer_safety::preferred:
        std::cout << "preferred\n";
        break;
    case std::pointer_safety::strict:
        std::cout << "strict\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

An output of:

```
relaxed
```

means that the implementation has a trivial implementation which does nothing at all.

libc++ outputs:

```
relaxed
```

VS-2015 outputs:

```
relaxed
```

gcc 5.0 outputs:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:10:13: error: 'get_pointer_safety' is not a member of 'std'
    switch (std::get_pointer_safety())
            ^
```

Comment: `g++` 8.2.0 also outputs `relaxed`, so `libstdc++` does not implement GC either.