# Visual C++ GC Interface How to enable it and which library to include

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, garbage-collection

I started learning GC interface in C++ and ran a few examples available on web in Visual 2019 C++ for below functions:

- [std::declare_reachable](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/declare_reachable/)
- [std::undeclare_reachable](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/undeclare_reachable/)
- [std::declare_no_pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/declare_no_pointers/)
- [std::undeclare_no_pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/undeclare_no_pointers/)

Each reference above has an example code which got compiled in my VC++ 2019 and successfully executed

What I am missing to understand that does VS2019 has GC by default enabled - I mean don't we need to enable some compiler switches or library to add for linking.

Also if GC is defautly enabled then why we do not have  'set_pointer_safety' but '[get_pointer_safety](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/get_pointer_safety/)' only?

Then how can we use the GC features in VC++ some example that the memory is de-allocated as a result of GC?

Comment: Are you allowed to use other tools like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) or [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or some other static source program analyzer ?

Comment: The point of smart pointers is, besides others,  to avoid gc entirely. You should not take example from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++ does not implement garbage collection, so the questions of whether/how to enable it or which libraries it requires are moot.

The presence of the listed functions does not mean that a GC exists. It only means that VC++ implements the interfaces mandated by C++11 that would *allow* a GC to work. But there is none such provided as of the latest version 2019, and the VC++ implementation of those functions is just no-ops, with the "*pointer safety model*" returned as `pointer_safety::relaxed` i.e. none at all. Quoting from the VC++ `memory` header:

```
// GARBAGE COLLECTION
enum class pointer_safety { relaxed, preferred, strict };

inline void declare_reachable(void*) {}

template <class _Ty>
_Ty* undeclare_reachable(_Ty* _Ptr) {
    return _Ptr;
}

inline void declare_no_pointers(char*, size_t) {}

inline void undeclare_no_pointers(char*, size_t) {}

inline pointer_safety get_pointer_safety() noexcept {
    return pointer_safety::relaxed;
}
```

From Stroustrup's [GC ABI](https://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#gc-abi) FAQ:

> ***relaxed:*** *safely-derived and not safely-derived pointers are treated equivalently; like C and C++98 [...]*

More on SO about C++11 GC:

- [Garbage Collection in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313405/garbage-collection-in-c11)
- [C++11: what is its GC interface, and how to implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728142/c11-what-is-its-gc-interface-and-how-to-implement)
- [How to use Minimal GC in VC++ 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800897/how-to-use-minimal-gc-in-vc-2013)

Answer (score 4):

> I started learning GC interface in C++

Did you read the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) ?

> Visual C++ GC Interface How to enable it and which library to include

<sup>As others explained, there is no real GC in Visual C++</sup>

### Writing a *simple* [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) is fairly easy.

Just read [the GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) for guidance, and/or the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), and/or [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lisp-in-small-pieces/66FD2BE3EDDDC68CA87D652C82CF849E) or this [*Uniprocessor Garbage Collection Techniques*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/15411-f14/misc/wilson94-gc.pdf) paper.

Notice that C++ garbage collection marking or copying routines for your GC could be *generated* by tools similar to [SWIG](http://swig.org/) in the spirit of the [s11n](http://www.s11n.net/) library.

If your code base is small (a few dozen thousands of C++ lines, and a few dozens of C++ `class`-es) you might even *generate* GC support routines with your own metaprogram (or using the [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) preprocessor or the [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) one or [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)). If you can and are allowed to compile your C++ code with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in July 2020), consider writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to generate garbage collection support C++ code. See also [this draft][9] report, and the references inside it. Notice [the garbage collector](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Type-Information.html) *inside* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

You could be interested by [Boehm's conservative GC](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/) library, or by [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), or by the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

But writing a state of the art and high-performance GC takes a lot of efforts, in particular when your C++ program is multi-threaded.

PS. On both [github](https://github.com/) and [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) and elsewhere you'll find several open source implementations in C or C++ of garbage collected languages, e.g. [this](https://github.com/Cheukyin/TemplatedPL) (or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](https://python.org/) or [GHC](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/) or [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/)). I recommend studying -for inspiration- their C++ or C source code. And [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) has internally its [own garbage collector](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Type-Information.html) (see also my old unmaintained [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project and several slides I wrote about it).